# Не работает nth-child в группе блоков созданных динамически

Tags: javascript, css

```js
    function addButtons () {
        let buttonBlock = document.getElementById("button-block");
        let typeButton;
        for (var i=0; i < 20; i++) {
          typeButton = document.createElement("div");
          typeButton.classList.add("type-button");
          buttonBlock.appendChild(typeButton);
          }
      }
    
    addButtons();
```

```css
    #button-block {
      position: absolute;
      left: 10px;
      bottom: 5px;
      width: 300px;
      height: 50px;
      background-color: transparent;
    }
    
    .type-button {
      float: left;
      margin: 2px;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      background-color: red;
      border-radius: 5px;
      box-shadow: -2px 3px 5px grey;
    }
    
    #button-block type-button:nth-child(11) {
      width: 90px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="button-block"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`type-button` является классом по этому правильно будет написать так:

```
#button-block .type-button:nth-child(11) {
    width: 90px;
}
```

Comment: да уж... Спасибо =)

Comment: @Александр прошу засчитать как ответ на данный вопрос (либо удалить вопрос), впредь пожалуйста будьте по внимательней и обращайтесь ща ответом если не получается решить задачу в течении не 2-3 минут, а более, спасибо.